# Battery management system circuit validation. Is my rough circuit design correct? Am I on the right path?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, battery-charging, power-electronics, bms

After referring to several pieces of literature, websites and several questions on Stack Exchange, I have designed the circuit of a battery management system and roughly sketched it for a 10s, 36 V, 2.5 Ah battery pack.

I would like to get my circuit validated whether I am going on correct path or not. I think it is correct because I referred to many papers following the same exact method and circuit, but still I need a validation. If is there anything that I need to change, please tell me.

Once it is validated I will proceed to create schematics.

Here is the rough BMS circuit:

[image: rough schematic]

- Battery pack: 36 V, 2.5 Ah
- [Battery monitoring IC: LTC60811-2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6811-1-6811-2.pdf)
- [Microcontroller: STM32F401RCT6](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/dm00086815-1797941.pdf)
- [Current sensing amplifier: AD8205](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8205.pdf)
- [Buck converter (42 V to 3.3 V): LTC3638](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3638fa.pdf)
- [MOSFETs: IPD088N06N3 G](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPD088N06N3-DS-v02_00-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ddc9372011e2b2351db4d5c)

I have already validated the internal circuits of each IC and also I have validated the power consumption.

I would like to get my whole circuit validated and need to know whether I am on the right path.

Comment: Battery monitoring chip is wrong part number. Add hyper links to all part data sheets.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you so much Andy . how about the circuit apart from the part number is everything okay

Comment: My only concern is how much imbalance current the monitoring IC can muster in order to keep charging into all cells fairly identical. Where does charging voltage enter the circuit?

Comment: Battery Monitoring IC will take care of the current consumption  and the charger positive and load positive is connected to the positive side of the battery pack externally   it works in circular path (from charger to the battery to the BMS and again to the charger back)since electrons travel from the negative side of the battery during discharge i have added only negative power rail in the circuit

Comment: The negative rail is designed in bidirectional way . so both while charging as well as discharging both positive current as well as negative current will travel through negative rail the current sensing will happen in both the sides if the current exceeds the threshold  while charging or discharging the respective Mosfets will cut-off the circuit. reference : https://patents.justia.com/patent/5883495  @Andyaka is is okay or is there any suggestions Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to add a comment, so see this as a Substitute.

A BMS should also monitor the battery temperature (best by a temperature sensor inside the battery pack next to the cells) besides the electrical characteristics. Then you are able to prevent charging in extreme temperature ranges.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir . i will definitely add an thermistor  based circuit in it . and Part from that is everything Okay shall i proceed to schematics.

Comment: From a hardware point of view (without checking the exact components) it looks quite good. You can recognize over/under-voltage, over-current and over/under-temperature. Additionally a SMD fuse on the BMS pcb in a Power rail would help to protect the cells from a short circuit from the load side. Afterwards the software functions to open the MOSFETs in case of an error have to be implemented.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.