# Which method is best method to amplify 3.3 v output to 10 v to drive MOSFET Switches with Low RDs ? NPN transistor or DC-DC boost Converter?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics

Iam using STM32F401 microcontroller to drivie mosfets for bidirectional current control for safe charging and discharging operation of a Battery pack.

My microcontroller maximum PWM output to drive mosfets are 3.3v . i would like to amplify 3.3v to 10v to drive the mosfets with low Rds for power consumption.

So when i search in internet i came up with two results to amplify 3.3v to 10v . one is NPN transistor common emitter configuration. another is DC-DC boost converter.

I would like to know which is the best method to amplify 3.3 v to 10 v to drive Mosfets.

**My Circuit:**
[image]

**In the above circuit i have used NPN transistor just for an understanding and completion of the circuit.**

**but I would like to know which method is best and efficient to use DC-DC boost converter or NPN Transistor**

Comment: Why are you not logged-in as muthu as per [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493588/battery-management-system-circuit-validation-is-my-rough-circuit-design-correct?noredirect=1#comment1256055_493588)

Comment: no we both are team mates we both are working on the same .project . I had this doubt so i Posted it.

Comment: Same handwriting.

Comment: Do you have 10 V available already? Can your MOSFETs handle 42 V on their gates?

Comment: @Andyaka From my Indian colleges handwriting, I’m starting to believe they were all drilled long and hard in school to produce identical handwriting.

Comment: @Andyaka no as i told we are working together , so the handwriting is not same, it is actually drawn by muthu...but i got the doubt so i posted that picture with the doubt in my mind. It would be great if you can suggest something.

Comment: You guys (Muthu and Sanya) need to communicate with each other because Muthu has already asked this same question. We're not here to act as your personal assistants you know.

Comment: Sure we will communicate. And so far because of quarantine we are not able to immidiately clarify our doubts in university. And Forums are created to assist students that's why we are posting.

Comment: @Sanya - Hi, Regarding your last comment: "*Forums are created to assist students that's why we are posting.*" (a) Stack Exchange sites are **not** forums and have extra, different, rules. Please see the [tour] where it says: "It's not a discussion forum". (b) There is no open-ended commitment to "assist students" - students must follow the same rules. For example, to ask a [good question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you should search first e.g. to avoid duplication with your teammate. || So you are welcome to ask questions, but follow the rules, please. Thanks :-)

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you for the information sir, I will definitely follow the rules. I was just looking forward for answer because here many people have experience. It was not duplication.We had a doubt on which to choose. My simple question was which method is more suitable for the same circuit, DC-DC converter or Transistor.  Moreover,as you said its open-ended and there is no commitment to assist,if it was found to be repititive to someone , they are not compelled to answer. It could be left unanserwed also. As you saw, harsh comments from some people is not expected. Anyways Thanks Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Normal method would be a PNP with a resistor e.g. 100K between emmitor and base to hold it off,

The base of the PNP is switched by an NPN transistor to ground (PNP base to NPN collector, NPN emmitor to ground and NPN base to micro via a resistance),

In this case it would also be wise to give the mosfet gates a weak pull down to ground to keep them off (the PNP will leak a tiny amount, which would pull up the voltage otheriwse), e.g. 47K,

Edit, missed the 42V, in this case you would fit a resistor in series with the PNP collector so that the divided voltage is about the 10V your after,